# GCM notification is not receiving when app is killed( not force kill)

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, google-cloud-messaging

I am happily receiving notifications when app is in background and foreground but when app is killed, I am not receiving notifications in some phones (like Xiaomi model phones eg mi3, etc.)

GCM message  0:1434141725194227%03b66390f9fd7ecd
broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg= (has extras) }

Although I am getting notifications in other phones like nexus, samsung, others. 
Did anyone also had similar problem?
Can someone explain me where I am wrong.

Here is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="<package_name>">

<permission android:name="<package_name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="<package_name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>


<application
    android:name="<package_name>.ApplicationSingleton"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="<package_name>.ui.activity.ReferralActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <receiver
        android:name="<package_name>.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="<package_name>" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="<package_name>"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

    <service android:name="<package_name>.gcm.GcmIntentService" />

    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


</application>
```

Comment: Do you have Google Play Services installed in the Xiaomi device?

Comment: Yes, Google play is installed that's why I am getting when app is running 
but not when app is killed.

Comment: Guess its a bug in Xiaomi. Read this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/xiaomi-mi-3/help/greenify-gcm-notification-t2883458

Comment: @user3265443 I am stuck with the same issue. Did you fixed it? These phones have an "Autostart" feature which if enabled ensures that you receive the notifications even if the app is removed from recent apps or in other terms killed. I don't know what makes this autostart enable on its own. Please help me out if you have fixed this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104161/not-receiving-gcm-push-notification-in-mi-phone-if-app-is-killed?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Autostart probably the best MIUI feature that doesn’t come enabled by default, but should.

What does autostart do? It basically starts the apps you select when the phone starts, so you never miss any notifications or updates.

To enable autostart for your apps, follow the steps below:

1. Tap on the **Security** app from the app screen.

You will not find this if you enter from the Settings menu, you have to tap directly on the app icon.

Open Security App:
[image: Open Security App]

2. Once in the Security app, tap on Permissions.
3. Tap on Autostart
4. Toggle the apps you want to enable Autostart for
5. Reboot your phone.

Now you are all set up with autostart!