# Not receiving GCM push notification in MI phone if app is killed

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I integrated GCM in my project to receive push notification from server. I am able to successfully receive push notification in all the devices (Nexus, Samsung etc), however, I am not receiving notifications on my Xiaomi MI phone.

When the app is running or is in background then I am receiving notification however if I kill the app (by swiping the app away from recent apps) then I don't receive any notification.

In pre-installed Security app there is an Auto-Start feature. Some apps have this auto-start feature turned ON and some don't. My app have this auto-start feature turned OFF. If I turn auto-start ON for my app then I start receiving notifications even if I kill the app.

How can I fix this issue? Please help me out.

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33936766/3140227

Comment: @VipulAsri The link you shared is for turning Auto-Start ON/OFF manually. I don't want the user to follow these steps manually. I want the Auto-Start to be by default enable when user installs my app. If other apps (Facebook, Whatsapp, line, linkedin) have this enabled by default then there must be some way to accomplish it via coding.

Comment: I think you have changed the os that if swipe the app away it will close the app totally for battery save. So you can try to set the gcm `priority to high`, or setting up `a separate service` to receive the GCM messages.

Comment: @bjiang I haven't changed the OS. I also tried creating a service which will keep always running but still no help.

Comment: @NiteshKhatri did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

Start AutoStart

```
Open Security App -> Permissions -> Auto Start Management.
Add/Enable your app as auto start apps
```

Start Lock Screen Notification

```
Open Settings App -> Notifications - Manage Notifications.
Tap on your App and select all cases.
```

i got success with this.. Hope it helps..

Comment: Is there any way to programatically turn on Auto Start for my app?

Comment: @KrishnaMeena no.. there is no way to do with programatically bcause its custom os in MI.

Comment: But I think for GMAIL its auto enabled than how they did?

Comment: MI Phone default setup with google services, whatsapp and i think fb also... even u can stop it also... MI manufacturer provide with this default ones..because all these apps are now a days daily need so...

Comment: @KrishnaMeena Once i have decompiled security apk of mi phone. and i found a file with list of package names (fb, messenger, snapchat, google apps, hike etc) for which they have default enabled auto start setting.